# How to resolve 'INS 30131 Initial setup required for the execution of installer validation failed' in Oracle installation?

Tags: windows, oracle

This error occurred during installation of Oracle on Windows Server 2008.
Details:

```
Cause - Failed to access the temporary location.
Action - Ensure that the current user has required permissions to access the temporary location.
Additional Information:
 - PRVG-1901 : failed to setup CVU remote execution framework directory C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\2\CVU_12.2.0.1.0_Administrator\ on nodes "rgfindbd"
 - Cause:  An operation requiring remote execution could not complete because
     the attempt to set up the Cluster Verification Utility remote
     execution framework failed on the indicated nodes at the
     indicated directory location because the CVU remote execution
     framework version did not match the CVU java verification
     framework version. The accompanying message provides detailed
     failure information.
 - Action:  Ensure that the directory indicated exists or can be created and
     the user executing the checks has sufficient permission to
     overwrite the contents of this directory. Also review the
     accompanying error messages and respond to them.

  Summary of the failed nodes rgfindbd
  - Version of exectask could not be retrieved from node "rgfindbd"
  - Cause: Cause Of Problem Not Available
  - Action: User Action Not Available
  - Version of exectask could not be retrieved from node "rgfindbd"
  - Cause: Cause Of Problem Not Available
  - Action: User Action Not Available
```

Comment: Any suggest to me error occured in windows 2008 server

Comment: Did you make sure you had sufficient rights when running the installer?

Comment: Hai yacc yes i have adminstator rights...

Comment: Ok, but how did you start it, via double-click or from console? Could you fix that error meanwhile?

Comment: [Setup] Run as adminstator . I was started  the oracle database installation..Till now i was not able to fix it yaac..

Comment: I have no clue. When looking up your error on Google I found this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/4032422 Check the last two post in this thread.

Comment: Ok thank you yaac...

Answer (score 4):

In the folder, where your setup.exe is, run:

```
setup -ignorePrereq -J"-Doracle.install.db.validate.supportedOSCheck=false"
```

Answer (score 2):

In administrator cmd go to your setup folder then:

For a client installation:
setup
-ignorePrereq

-J"-Doracle.install.client.validate.clientSupportedOSCheck=false"

For a server installation:
setup
-ignorePrereq -J"-Doracle.install.db.validate.supportedOSCheck=false"

Comment: The clientSupportedOSCheck version worked for me when installing the client. - Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you to

check if  RemoteExecService.exe is running from your temp location,

for example C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Temp\oraremservice.

If it does, then kill the process and delete the oraremservice folder. 
Rerun your installation

Answer (score 0):

Run cmd as administrator 
Locate the folder of the setup 
And use this 
setup -ignorePrereq -J"-Doracle.install.db.validate.supportedOSCheck=false"

Answer (score 0):

Delete the **oraremservicev2** folder in **C:\Users\{name}\AppData\Local\Temp** location  and continue the installation. Working fine

Answer (score -1):

this work in my case

```
# chmod 777 -R /tmp
```

Comment: @PAVANVARMA . Yes Bro